# Reshape multiple numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I have the following numpy array:

```
X = [[1],
     [2],
     [3],
     [4]]

Y = [[5],
     [6],
     [7],
     [8]]

Z = [[9],
     [10],
     [11],
     [12]]
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
H = [[1,5,9],
     [2,6,10],
     [3,7,11]
     [4,8,12]]
```

Is there a way get this result using numpy.reshape?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) -

```
np.column_stack((X,Y,Z))
```

Or [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) along `axis=1` -

```
np.concatenate((X,Y,Z),axis=1)
```

Or [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) -

```
np.hstack((X,Y,Z))
```

Or [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) along `axis=0` and then do multi-dim transpose -

```
np.stack((X,Y,Z),axis=0).T
```

Reshape applies on an array, not to stack or concatenate arrays together. So, `reshape` alone doesn't make sense here.

One could argue using `np.reshape` to give us the desired output, like so -

```
np.reshape((X,Y,Z),(3,4)).T
```

But, under the hoods its doing the stacking operation, which AFAIK is something to convert to array with `np.asarray` -

```
In [453]: np.asarray((X,Y,Z))
Out[453]: 
array([[[ 1],
        [ 2],
        [ 3],
        [ 4]],

       [[ 5],
        [ 6],
        [ 7],
        [ 8]],

       [[ 9],
        [10],
        [11],
        [12]]])
```

We just need to use `multi-dim transpose` on it, to give us a `3D` array version of the expected output -

```
In [454]: np.asarray((X,Y,Z)).T
Out[454]: 
array([[[ 1,  5,  9],
        [ 2,  6, 10],
        [ 3,  7, 11],
        [ 4,  8, 12]]])
```

Comment: Since the arrays are already (4,1), anything but `np.concatenate` is overkill.  They either do unneeded shape tests, or create a 3d array (`stack`  and `asarray` variants).

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget `np.c_` (I don't see the need for `np.reshape`):

```
np.c_[X,Y,Z]
# array([[ 1,  5,  9],
#        [ 2,  6, 10],
#        [ 3,  7, 11],
#        [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this (faster) solution?

```
In [16]: np.array([x.squeeze(), y.squeeze(), z.squeeze()]).T
Out[16]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

---

*Efficiency* (descending order)

```
# proposed (faster) solution
In [17]: %timeit np.array([x.squeeze(), y.squeeze(), z.squeeze()]).T
The slowest run took 7.40 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.36 µs per loop

# Other solutions
In [18]: %timeit np.column_stack((x, y, z))
The slowest run took 5.18 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.18 µs per loop

In [19]: %timeit np.hstack((x, y, z))
The slowest run took 4.49 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 16 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit np.reshape((x,y,z),(3,4)).T
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.6 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit np.c_[x, y, z]
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.9 µs per loop
```

Comment: You should mention that your proposed solution results in a non-contiguous (well, non-C-contiguous, anyway) array, which I suspect is why it is faster. As a consequence, later row access will presumably be slower.